# How can I use Node.js to get the value of a child under random USERid and keys

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It's a simple concept but yet finding the right answer is ridiculously stressing.  Use Firebase Functions w/ Node.js to pull the "itemsExpires" (date) from the Firebase database.   The parent node is the userId (random string) and each item is stored under a key node (another random string)..  So, here's what the firebase database looks like:

```
firebase-database-name
+ 82hfijcbwjbjfbergjagbk_USERID
  + "My Stuff"
    + gnjfgsdkfjsdf_ITEMkey
      -- "item name": whatever
      -- "itemExpires": 05-01-2017
      -- "itemType": whatever too
    + an3jeejwiag_ITEMkey
      -- "item name": whatever
      -- "itemExpires": 06-01-2017
      -- "itemType": whatever too
    + zzzndjgabblsbl_ITEMkey
      -- "item name": whatever
      -- "itemExpires": 07-01-2017
      -- "itemType": whatever too
```

I'm not asking for someone to write the code, a good reference will do but there are so many ways to call data and all I'm finding are the ways to Call using a structured tree and not one with random id's and keynumbers.

*** Basically, my goal here is to run a 3rd party cron job through Firebase Functions that runs through each item entry and checks the expiration date against today's date.  This is the wall I'm against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bradley I am yet unclear as to what you want to do exactly. I suppose you intend on having multiple users (not just one as in the example) with multiple Items and compare the current date against the expiration date of all items for every user at a specified time (using cron). There are some considerations you should take into account here :

- Do you really need cron ? ( or can you solve your problems more easily and natively with a javascript plain setInterval() ? )
- How often are you going to check your entire database and how big is that database?

OK. So to explain, the first consideration is just a thought and the logic behind it should be pretty obvious. The second consideration takes some explaining. Since I believe your firebase data will NOT be static and will constantly change you need to find a way to get these changes inside you node script.

If you do not intend on calling your scheduled task too often and the database is not a mammoth (taking ages to load) you could just do the following :

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('yourServiceAccountPath.json');
firebase.initializeApp({
   credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "youDatabaseURL"  
});
setInteval(function(){ // or cron schedule
  firebase.database().ref().once('value',function(snapshot){
    let allYourUsers = snapshot.val();
    // iterate through them all 
    // and do what you gotta do
  });
},10000); // your interval in milliseconds
```

However this approach just loads once all your database each time you want to check all items. If you have other data in the database, consider adding users to a seperate path and load just that path. This approach is not recommended if your users are quite many and/or you want them to be checked very often. If such is the case and your data does not change very often you could consider this alternative:

Here you use the on function to update your data as it is edited and set the checking part seperate like so :

```
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('yourServiceAccountPath.json');
firebase.initializeApp({
   credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "youDatabaseURL"  
});

const  databaseRef=firebase.database().ref();    
let allYourUsers;
let allYourUsersStaticCopy;

databaseRef.on('value',function(snapshot){
   allYourUsers = snapshot.val();
});

setInteval(function(){ // or cron schedule
  if ( allYourUsers ) { // to ensure that data has loaded at least once 
                        // (startup considerations)
     allYourUsersStaticCopy = Object.assign({},allYourUsers);
    // iterate through the static copy in order to avoid 
    // you data changing while you are accesing it
    // and do what you gotta do
  }
},10000); // your interval in milliseconds
```

The upside with the second piece of code is that your data is loaded every time there is a change and not every time your check runs. If however your data changes very often (additions,deletions and edits) this approach might not be optimum.

In the case that your script runs often enough, the database is big enough, and the changes are often enough to prevent any of the above to be efficient, you might want to consider the optimum solution : loading your users once and then attaching listeners for the child added,removed and changed to update your existing users object. Thus you receive only changes and not a whole snapshot. If such is the case you can read about the mentioned listeners in the firebase docs and I can squeeze in some extra code. Just let me know.

Hope this long post helps!

Comment: Thank you for the information.  All of the items that each user submits to the database needs to be check automatically and regularly (each day) so proper notifications can be sent out (which is why I was thinking the use of cron jobs).  This worked perfectly when I had the website in PHP/mySQL but since I've switched to iOS and Firebase, I'm only familiar with what I've used before.

Comment: It needs to run a check on all of the expiration dates in the database and send a notification to a user if their item has expired.

Comment: Well, each day is actually quite a long time for this case. Assuming you have a database sizing up to a few tens of MBs, the first scrap of code will work just fine. You also probably don't really need cron for that, a simple javascript interval will do the job, all you have to do is set the interval to the amount of milliseconds in a day. If however you need to execute these tasks at a specific time during the day, using cron can easy things up quite a bit (not that it cant be implemented with pure js, but not quite worth it).

Comment: We can give it a shot.  I appreciate your feedback..  I just needed, at the least, a point in the right direction.  Thank you again..

Comment: ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/private/var/folders/c3/fnyhf3g160qfbz72z6fp_800gn/T/fbfn_12005frpqRo6UlA/index.js:10:1)

Comment: Are you trying to run similar code as stated above in the firebase functions ? Keep in mind that the pieces of code I wrote are node.js examples, code you intend to run in firebase functions has some differences. From personal experience firebase functions are not quite "suitable" for periodic tasks (doing smthing every some time) since they are trigger based (on write,on change etc). More on firebase functions here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started or feel free to ask!

Comment: I knew that.  I'm so scatter brained with this project now, I can't even keep up with what I'm trying to use to get it accomplished.  It used to be a simple PHP website.  What would take me days to finish using mySQL has taken MONTHS to do now that I'm trying to get things working with Firebase.  It's brick wall after brick wall after brick wall. I've got Database working perfect is Swift, but when it comes to the web and node JS functions, it's starting to make myself question if I should even other with it.

Comment: But yes, I need something to trigger the database daily and I was trying to get the function to do it.

Comment: From what I have seen, firebase functions do not have a periodic trigger, they have only event triggers. In order to achieve what you want, you would have to use a dummy database trigger (such as writing a dummy value). However, this is approach is not actually the best and I will tell you why. Who would be responsible to modify this dummy value daily ? A client-side entity? Very bad practice. A server side entity? Well if you have a server side entity doing that, you might as well make it do all the job ( the code I wrote above). Do you see my point?

Comment: I understand that with Functions but there has GOT to be some way of pulling this off.  It's not a hard concept and I'm sure I'm not the only one using it.  I need SOMETHING to trigger daily a search through every item in the Firebase Database, match the dates with the current date, and send a notification to the appropriate user if their item is expired.  I don't see why I'm still sitting here after months still banging my head in the wall trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Firebase set up properly within your node project, you can do a one time read for your ITEMkey entries.  Something like this:

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("82hfijcbwjbjfbergjagbk_USERID").child("My Stuff");

ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
        var contents = snapshot.val();
        // Data returned here will be an object with all children
        // nodes under "My Stuff".  You can access it by calling
        // snapshot.val() like I did above.
}
```

Comment: That's the problem though.. I need it to check the children of each of those UserId's.. not just one.

Comment: Firebase will return an array of all the child nodes in the callback function.  See my edits.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment:  Firebase will return an object of the child nodes;  Not an array.